# Webpack/html-loader <a> tag href resolve

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

I've set up aliases in my webpack config file. It works fine for JS, CSS imports and img src attributes. However I'd like to build a gallery in the HTML file with the standard lightbox setup:

`<a href="~Images/foo.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery1"><img src="~Images/foo_thumb.jpg"></a>`

The problem is that while the `img src` is resolved by the html-loader, the `a href` is not. Is there any setting or additional plugin that can resolve `a href` values?

Answer (score 1):

for webpack 5 in options add source for link tag like this

p.s. '...' in list arr is require for extend default [supported tags and attributes](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#sources)

```
{
  test: /\.html$/i,
  include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/views'),
  use: {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      esModule: false,
      sources: {
        list: [
          '...',
          {
            tag: 'a',
            attribute: 'href',
            type: 'src'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's enough to add the `a href` to the list of supported attributes of the `html-loader` plugin. So in the webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'html-loader',
  options: {
    attributes: {
      // ...
      {
        tag: 'a',
        attribute: 'href',
        type: 'src'
      }
    }
  }
}
```